# javascript variables to a server through ajax problem

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

My goal is to send  data to the server through Ajax.

But the server doesn't receive data exactly.

Here is the code I wrote.

in javascript

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5;
var f = { 'h':11, 'i':22, 'j':33};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd': d, 'e': e,'dataImportant': f},
    success: function(result){
        /* do something */
    },
    error: function(result){
        /* do something */
    }
});
```

in php

```
function getAjax(){
    $a = $this->input->post("a");
    $b = $this->input->post("b");
    $c = $this->input->post("c");
    $d = $this->input->post("d");
    $e = $this->input->post("e");
    $f = $this->input->post("dataImportant");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($f);
    echo "</pre>";
    return;
}
```

result:

```
<pre></pre>
```

I intended to get the data in the form of an array.

but it could not be reached well

what is my mistake?

Comment: I removed camel-case notation, and had no problems.

Comment: dataImportant X dataimportant O . Maybe camel-case notation is not a  way of available through Ajax

Answer (score 1):

Are `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, etc... in your javascript defined variables? If not, and you are just palying:

```
var f = { h:'11', i:'22', j:'33'};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c', 'd':'d', 'e':'e','f':'f' },
    success: function(result){
        /* do something */
    },
    error: function(result){
        /* do something */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the quotes around your data declaration:

```
  data: { a:a, b:b, c:c, d:d, e:e, f:f},
```

The first letter defines what you are naming the value that follows.

```
{name:value, name:value}
```

You would only need the quotes around the value if you are defining it in the data declaration

```
data: {a:'a',b:'b',etc}
```

Try my first example and see if your php script can echo the sent values.

Comment: JSON can use string literals to define object variables which is especially useful for special characters: `obj={'hyphen-ated':'foo'}` is perfectly valid.